# Is any substring of a hash (md5, sha1) more "random" than another?

Tags: md5, sha1, hashcode, sha256

Here's 3 example md5 hashes

```
$ md5 -s "1" && md5 -s "2" && md5 -s "3"
MD5 ("1") = c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b
MD5 ("2") = c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c
MD5 ("3") = eccbc87e4b5ce2fe28308fd9f2a7baf3
```

Say I wanted to take 8 characters from any hash. Is the beginning part of the hash particularly more "random" than the end? middle? Or are all substrings equally "random"?

Comment: In my opinion, "random" is not the right word here. Hash functions are as deterministic as they get; there is no randomness involved at all. You shold probably ask if a substring of a hash has the same collusion resistance as the orginal (accounting for the different length, of course).

Comment: I was just about to ask this very question..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I was curious myself, so I went ahead and wrote a [program](http://pastebin.com/CfBuhB4L) to test this. You'll need [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) to compile the code.

Disclaimer:
When it comes to cryptography, or even just mathematics in general, I know just enough to shoot myself in the foot. So, take the following results with a grain of salt and keep in mind that I only have a cursory knowledge of the tools I'm using.

I only sampled three substrings: the first 8 bytes, the middle 8 bytes, and the last 8 bytes. Long story short, they're equally random.

However, when using a smaller sample space, it appears as if the last 8 bits are slightly more random. The larger the sampling space, the closer all three substrings approach complete randomness.

---

1000 iterations:

```
First:  0.995914
Middle: 0.996546
Last:   0.998104
```

5000 iterations:

```
First:  0.998387
Middle: 0.998624
Last:   0.999501
```

10000 iterations:

```
First:  0.999614
Middle: 0.999457
Last:   1
```

30000 iterations:

```
First:  1
Middle: 1
Last:   1
```

---

"Randomness" is measured by Crypto++'s [MaurerRandomnessTest](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_maurer_randomness_test.html) class. For reference, the executable compiled from the above code has a randomness value of `0.632411` and a copy of Shakespeare's Macbeth downloaded from Project Gutenburg has a randomness value of `0.566991`.

Answer (score 14):

Nitpick: "random" is the wrong word to use here, since hash functions are deterministic.

As for answering what you mean :), a desirable property of hash functions is achieving the [Avalanche effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect): basically, to have every bit of input cause drastic changes to the output. So, for a well-designed hash, every substring should be affected equally often ("*be as random*") as any other.

Comment: I put the word random in quotes for this very reason :) +1 for linking to the avalanche effect.

Comment: This should be the answer as it accurately answers and it expresses the reason _why_

Answer (score 12):

All substrings of a good hash (and md5 is reasonably good despite being cryptographically unsafe) are equally random, so yes, take any bits you like from the string, they should be equally distributed.

Answer (score 0):

Measuring the randomness of the output of a hash function can be done using Statistical tests done on pseudo-random number generators.
According to the [Handbook of Applied Cryptography](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/) §5.4.4 (sample chapters available for free), there are five basic tests:

1. Frequency test (monobit test)
2. Serial test (two-bit test)
3. Poker test
4. Runs test
5. Autocorrelation test

Then, of course, there's the Maurer's universal statistical test that kurige has already mentioned.